# How to overwrite a file read by polars?

Tags: python-polars

```
df = pl.read_ipc(path)
df.write_ipc(path)
```

> called `Result::unwrap()` on an `Err` value: Os { code: 5, kind:
> PermissionDenied, message: "Acesso negado." }

"Acesso negado" is "Permission denied" in portuguese, which I imagine is a message from my system.

**How can I overwrite the read file?**

In my original code, my aim is to read the file, concatenate with new info and write to the same file. I suppose the answer is easy, but wasn't able to solve it.

Answer (score 0):

I think this might be a bug. I've tested first with writing, reading and re-writing a csv file, and everything works as expected. Changing only the `*_csv` to `*_ipc` then throws an exception:

```
df = pl.DataFrame(data)

df.write_ipc("output")
#df = pl.read_ipc("output") Original line, causes fault
df = pl.read_ipc("output", memory_map=False) # Fixed, works as expected
df.write_ipc("output")
```

//EDIT// Updated code above, as this resolved the issue for me.

Result, albeit slightly different to yours:

```
PanicException: called `Result::unwrap()` on an `Err` value: Os { code: 1224, kind: Uncategorized, message: "The requested operation cannot be performed on a file with a user-mapped section open." }
```

Can you write the output to a different file for now? That works for me, simply by changing the final write to `df.write_ipc("output2")`

Comment: Sadly, changing the name would mean that I'd have to keep increasing that name or keeping a previous and a current file, something in that line. 
That said, you gave me an idea changing the format. Changing from ipc to parquet solved my problem and is good enough for me

Comment: Someone posted on polars github also:
https://github.com/pola-rs/polars/issues/8886.
If the answer appears, I warn you

Comment: Yeah that was me, and the fix Ritchie suggested worked. Are you 100% sure the file isn't locked somehow else? Another application or something?

Comment: Oh, fair enough.
Yeah, I am sure. I even copied any feather file I had to another folder and got same error with it.
Pretty strange, but I'll not look mucher further, since .parquet solves the issue and most of my files I have to keep renaming them anyway.
Thank you!